# Is there a single word for "interesting" and "varied"?

Tags: single-word-requests

As in "NotAlwaysRight.com is the perfect website for those of us who have had the 'pleasure' of working in the -interesting and varied- field of employ that is customer service."

A word that replaces the 'pleasure' with something more appropriate that means "quixotic, confounding, disturbing, hilarious, and unbelievable" would be useful as well, but I don't think such a word exists, at least, not in English.

Comment: Can you please remove the name of the website from the question? It seems like a self promotion of sorts. As to the question, in the title, you are asking for a single word for "interesting" and "varied", while in its content you seem to be asking for a word to replace "pleasure". Please clarify as to the purpose of this question by editing it and ensure it is following community guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe *[eclectic](http://thesaurus.com/browse/eclectic?s=b)* comes closest: "selecting what seems best of various styles, methods, or ideas".

Comment: Thank you Bill Franke.. Though I've elected not to go with Eclectic, because this is a bit too positive of a word, it lead me to "multifarious" which has the flourish I was seeking, yet is more neutral.

Comment: Well, it's your choice, of course, but I have to disagree that _eclectic_ is "too positive": it's an insult to all purists and praise to most pragmatists. _Multifarious_ shares the same ending as _nefarious_, which means "flagrantly wicked or impious : evil", and means merely "having or occurring in great variety : diverse", which isn't necessarily the same as _interesting_.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing "pleasure" with "opportunity". Otherwise you are describing "customer service" twice. And perhaps, "fascinating" might work well. It also carries a potential positive sense, but at the same time clearly hints at less positive possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that *interesting* and *varied* have considerable overlap. How many things are "interesting, but not varied", for example? [Cosmic background radiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_background_radiation), perhaps?

So I think the sense in OP's example is *interesting **because** it's "varied"*. Which I'd call...

> [stimulating](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stimulating) - *inspiring **new** ideas or enthusiasm*

Answer (score 0):

It's not a single word, but the hyphenated phrase *never-dull* could work to replace interesting and varied. And you could use *misfortune* instead of *pleasure*:

> *NotAlwaysRight.com is the perfect website for those of us who have had the misfortune of working in the never-dull field of employ that is customer service.*

One definition of the idiom ["never a dull moment"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/never+a+dull+moment) says:

> something interesting is always happening